# Impute only certain NA's for a variable in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and exploring different beautiful options in it. I'm working on a data frame where I have a variable with 900 missing values, i.e `NA`s.
I want to impute 3 different values for `NA`s;

- 1st 300 NA's with Value 1.
- 2nd 300 NA's with Value 2.
- 3rd 300 NA's with Value 3.

There are a total of 23272 rows in the data.

```
dim(data)
[1] 23272    2

colSums(is.na(data))
month    year
884      884

summary(data$month)
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    NA's
1977 1658 1837 1584 1703 1920 1789 2046 1955 2026  1845  2048  884
```

If we check the month 8,10 and 12. There is no much differences, Hence thought of assigning these 3 months to NA by splitting at the ratio (300:300:284). Usually we go my MODE, but I want to try this approach.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example and show expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you a have a long list, some of the values of which are NAs:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(val = sample(c(1:3, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

We can keep a running tally of NA's and assign those to the imputed value using integer division with %/%.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(NA_num = if_else(is.na(val),
                          cumsum(is.na(val)),
                          NA_integer_),
         imputed = NA_num %/% 100 + 1)
```

Output:

```
df2 %>%
  slice(397:410)  # based on manual examination using this seed

   val NA_num imputed
1   NA     98       1
2   NA     99       1
3    3     NA      NA
4    1     NA      NA
5    1     NA      NA
6    3     NA      NA
7    3     NA      NA
8    2     NA      NA
9   NA    100       2
10   1     NA      NA
11  NA    101       2
12   2     NA      NA
13   1     NA      NA
14   2     NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, I think this will work.

Basically, filter the NAs to a new table, do the calc and merge it back.  Assume the new_dt is the OG data where you filter to only contain the NAs

```
library('tidyverse');
new_dt = data.frame(x1 =rep(1:900), x2= NA) %>%  filter(is.na(x2)) %>%
mutate(23 = case_when(row_number()%/%300==0 ~1,
                      row_number()%/%300==1 ~2,
                      row_number()%/%300==2 ~3))
dt <- rbind(dt,new_dt)
```